# nodejs get data from mysql and send to Client

Tags: c#, mysql, node.js, wpf

i have a problem.

when i used nodejs get data from mysql and send to Client. data form mysql like string `"Th&agrave;nh phần"`, when display on C# WPF Client, i don't know how to show that string to "Thành phần".

please help me this problem.

thanks!

Comment: Is it correctly stored in DB ?

Comment: in db stored by utf8_general_ci and in db the string `"Th&agrave;nh phần"` but if show this string in html the string "Thành phần"

Comment: Did you use the meta tag for UTF8 in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use the meta tag for UTF8.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: this error by display in C# WPF form, not in  HTML :(

Comment: i sloved, that add System.web refrences to project and encode by System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()